# WooCommerce 3.0 enqueue bundled scripts and styles, zoom, photoswipe

Tags: woocommerce

I was using prettyphoto in my WooCommerce Addon, and it was loading from WooCommerce files, but in v 3.0 WooCommerce has removed the prettyphoto and started using other scripts like

- flexslider
- zoom
- photoswipe

I want to enqueue their these bundled scripts, but can't find a function to do that. Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I fully understand your problem, but if I do maybe this can help:

in your **function.php** add these lines:

```
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'photoswipe_gallery_setup' );

function photoswipe_gallery_setup() {
  add_theme_support( 'wc-product-gallery-zoom' );
  add_theme_support( 'wc-product-gallery-lightbox' );
  add_theme_support( 'wc-product-gallery-slider' );
}
```

This will enable support for [PhotoSwipe](http://photoswipe.com)
You can enable/disable features deleting/commenting the correstonding line.

[credits](https://createandcode.com/broken-photo-gallery-and-lightbox-after-woocommerce-3-0-upgrade/)

Comment: Glad it worked. Please, mark the answer as Solution. Thanks

Comment: I did it already, but as my reputation is below 15, it will not appear yet publicly.